# getting ORA-01722: invalid number error while inserting form data from webpage

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, jdbc

Im getting ORA-01722 error while inserting data from jsp form into the oracle database. i know that this error is pointing out to me that i am trying to insert a character string inside a number datatype but the problem is that everything looks to be fine to me but still im getting the error

here is the code i use.

roomregister.jsp

```
<%
String roomcategory=request.getParameter("category");
if(roomcategory==null)
{
    response.sendRedirect("categoryrooms.jsp");
    return;
}
//out.println(roomcategory);
%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function ()
{
    //getRoomsByCategory();
}
        );
    var roomcategory="<%=roomcategory%>";

   /* function f1()
    //{
      //  var nrooms=$("#hdmaxrooms").val()-1;
        //alert(nrooms);
    }*/
    function chooseRoom(roomno)
    {
        $("#txtroomno").val(roomno);
    }

    function roombook()
    {
        var gender="";
        if(document.getElementById("txtmale").checked)
            gender="Male";
          if(document.getElementById("txtfemale").checked)
            gender="Female";
        if(gender=="")
            {
                alert("Please select a gender");
                return ;
            }
        var receiptno=$("#txtreceiptno").val();
        var name=$("#txtname").val();
        var address=$("#txtaddress").val(); 
        var idproof=$("#txtidproof").val();
        var dob=$("#txtdob").val();
        var contact=$("#txtcontact").val();
        var roomno=$("#txtroomno").val();
        var fromdate=$("#txtfromdate").val();
        var todate=$("#txttodate").val();
        var roomcategory=$("#txtroomcategory").val();
        var noofguestname=$("#txtnoofguestname").val();
        var charge=$("#txtcharge").val();
        var purpose=$("#txtpurpose").val();

        var bookingamount=$("#txtbookingamount").val();


        var url="bookrooms.jsp?receiptno="+ receiptno + "&name=" + name + "&address=" + address + "&idproof=" + idproof + "&dob=" + dob + "&gender="+ gender + "&contact=" + contact + "&roomno="
        + roomno + "&fromdate=" + fromdate +"&todate="+ todate +  "&roomcategory=" + roomcategory + "&noofguestname=" + noofguestname +
        "&charge=" + charge + "&purpose=" + purpose + "&bookingamount=" + bookingamount;

          var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("GET",url,true);
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function (){roomBookResponse(xhr);};
                xhr.send();
                //alert(url);

    }

      function roomBookResponse(xhr)
         {
             if(xhr.readyState!=4)
                 return ;
             //getRoomsByCategory();
             $("#diverrors").html(xhr.responseText);
            // alert("xZXZX" + xhr.responseText);
         }

         function getroom()
         {
            var fromdate =$("#txtfromdate").val();
            var todate =$("#txttodate").val();


            var url="roomsforbooking.jsp?fromdate="+ fromdate + "&todate=" + todate + "&category=" + roomcategory ;
                //alert(url);

          var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("GET",url,true);
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function (){getRoomResponse(xhr);};
                xhr.send();
                //alert(url);

         }
          function getRoomResponse(xhr)
         {
             if(xhr.readyState!=4)
                 return ;
            // getRoomsByCategory();
             $("#diverrors").html(xhr.responseText);
            // alert("xZXZX" + xhr.responseText);
         }
</script>

<font color="white">

<div id="divroomsbycategory"></div>




<div id="image" class="image">

<center>
    <table  class="divcenter" width="60%" border="0">
        <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">ROOM BOOKING</td></tr>

         <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"> <div id="diverrors"></div> </td></tr>
         <tr><td><BR>Receipt_No</td><td><BR><input type="text" id="txtreceiptno"/></td></tr>
         <tr><td>Name</td><td><input type="text" id="txtname"/></td></tr>
         <tr><td>Address</td><td><input type="text" id="txtaddress"/></td></tr>
         <tr><td>Id_Proof</td><td><input type="text" id="txtidproof"/></td></tr>
         <tr><td>Date_of_Birth</td><td><input type="text" id="txtdob"/></td></tr>

         <tr><td>Gender</td><td>Male<input type="radio" id="txtmale" value="male" name="gender"/>
         Female<input type="radio" id="txtfemale" value="female" name="gender"/></td></tr>


         <tr><td>Contact</td><td><input type="text" id="txtcontact"/></td></tr>
         <tr><td> Room_No</td><td>
                 <input type="text" id="txtroomno" readonly="readonly"/>
                 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                 <input type="button" value="GET" onclick="getroom();" class="divbutton"/></td></tr>


         <tr><td>From_Date</td><td><input type="text" id="txtfromdate"/></td></tr>
         <tr><td>TO-date</td><td><input type="text" id="txttodate"/></td></tr>
         <tr><td>Room_Category</td><td><input type="text" id="txtroomcategory"  readonly="readonly"  value="<%=roomcategory%>"/></td></tr>
         <tr><td>No_Of_Guest</td><td><input type="text" id="txtnoofguestname"/></td></tr>
         <tr><td>Charge</td><td><input type="text" id="txtcharge"/></td></tr>
         <tr><td>Purpose</td><td><input type="text" id="txtpurpose"/></td></tr>



         <tr><td>Booking-Amount</td><td><input type="text" id="txtbookingamount"/></td></tr>



         <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><BR><input type="button" value="SUBMIT" onclick="roombook();" class="divbutton"/></td></tr>
         <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><div id="divroomsbycategory"></div></td></tr>
    </table>
</center>

</div>  
         </font>    
         <style>
            .divbutton:hover
            {
                border: solid white;
               background-color:  seagreen;
            }
            .divcenter:hover


            {
                 border: solid;
                border-top-color:  white;
                border-bottom-color:  white;
                border-left-color: white;
                border-right-color: white;


            }
            .image
            {
                width: 100%;
                height: 600px;
                background-image: url("images/332.jpg");
            }
        </style>
```

bookrooms.jsp

```
<%@page import="utilitiespackage.Date"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="dbpackage.DBConnector"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="validationspackage.Validations"%>

  <%
    try
    {
String receiptno=request.getParameter("receiptno");
String name=request.getParameter("name");
String address=request.getParameter("address");
String idproof=request.getParameter("idproof");
String dob=request.getParameter("dob");
String gender=request.getParameter("gender");
String contact=request.getParameter("contact");
String roomno=request.getParameter("roomno");
String fromdate=request.getParameter("fromdate");
String todate=request.getParameter("todate");
String roomcategory=request.getParameter("roomcategory");
String noofguestname=request.getParameter("noofguestname");
String charge=request.getParameter("charge");
String purpose=request.getParameter("purpose");

String bookingamount=request.getParameter("bookingamount");

 //Connection con=DBConnector.getConnection(session);

PreparedStatement ps=DBConnector.getPreparedStatement(session, "insert into roomregister values ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
ps.setString(1,receiptno);
ps.setString(2,name);
ps.setString(3,address);
ps.setString(4,idproof);
ps.setString(5,contact);
ps.setString(6,roomno);
ps.setString(7,fromdate);
ps.setString(8,roomcategory);
ps.setString(9,noofguestname);
ps.setString(10,charge);
ps.setString(11,purpose);
ps.setString(12,gender);
ps.setString(13,dob);
ps.setString(14,bookingamount);

Date d1=new Date(fromdate);
Date d2=new Date(todate);
for(;Date.compare(d1, d2)<0;d1.advance())
{
    ps.setString(6, "" + d1);
    ps.executeUpdate();
}




out.println(Validations.setSuccess("Booked"));

//String message=Validations.setSuccess("deleted");
//out.println(message);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
        out.println(Validations.setError(ex));

    }
%>
```

my database table:

[image]

error that i am getting:
[image]

Comment: you need to show `roomregister` table definition, at least one of column is a number

Comment: *The use of scriptlets (those <% %> things) in JSP is indeed highly discouraged since the birth of taglibs (like JSTL) and EL (Expression Language, those ${} things) way back in 2001.* see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please do not put code like that into a JSP page. Create a servlet or a custom JSP tag to process that outside of JSP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ps.setString(1,receiptno);`

isn't that a "number" field and you are calling setString?

[The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int,%20java.lang.String)) for `java.sql.PreparedStatement` has this to say:

> Note: The setter methods (setShort, setString, and so on) for setting IN parameter values must specify types that are compatible with the defined SQL type of the input parameter. For instance, if the IN parameter has SQL type INTEGER, then the method setInt should be used.

Comment: it shows incompatible types: String cannot be  converted into int error if i try to use int instead of string. but even if the number is in string format it still gets inserted in the number datatype right? for example lets say im instering number 101 if i insert it with quotes like '101' it still gets inserted regardless being string type.

Comment: Great, and that is because you have receiptno defined as String receiptno=request.getParameter("receiptno"); Why don't you change it to int first using Integer.parseInt(receiptno); You need to make sure all the parameters are correct. Having a "String" datatype for integer/number just delays error to lower stack

Comment: i converted them into int by using integer.parseint() to all number values that i am inserting but im still getting the same error :(

Comment: Still getting invalid number issue or invalid date issue?  You shall enable jdbc tracing and see which column and value is giving issue https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/diagnose.htm

Comment: ok thanks :) i will look into it .btw i was still getting the invalid number issue.

Comment: ps.setString(6, "" + d1) and ps.setString(6, "" + roomnumber)

Why is that both going to 6th location for roomno. There u may be doing it wrong

Comment: thank you very much bro for helping. :) as you pointed out it seems that in my code it was trying to insert 2 different entries in the same column . i.e my room number as well as the date values were both going into the roomno (number) field. and the date being in 'dd-mon-yyyy' format would actually give me the above error. THANK YOU @user:2181703
for helping me fixing the errors. my code is finally working now all thanks to you :)